# Split multiple-fasta files according to header

Tags: unix, awk, fasta

I am beginner in bioinformatics and I am trying to create sub-multiple fasta files from several multiple-fasta files.

So I have hundreds of fasta files containing hundreads of fasta lines (sequences with headers). I want to separate this fasta in different new fasta files according to the species name (indication in the header).

I have files like that : 
CL0073reads.fas

```
>>CL0073reads.fas_ang4836665r
TAGGCAGGCGTGGGGGTTTGT
>CL0073reads.fas_ang4864845r
CCTCTTCGGCCCTCA
>CL0073reads.fas_atl679495r
CAAGGACCGTTAGGGGC
>CL0073reads.fas_alb178305r
GCTGACGGCAACGTTAG
```

I want :
CL0073reads_ang.fas

```
`>CL0073reads.fas_ang4836665r
TAGGCAGGCGTGGGGGTTTGT
>CL0073reads.fas_ang4864845r
CCTCTTCGGCCCTCA`
```

CL0073reads_atl.fas

```
`>CL0073reads.fas_atl679495r
CAAGGACCGTTAGGGGC`
```

CL0073reads_abl.fas

```
`>CL0073reads.fas_alb178305r
GCTGACGGCAACGTTAG`
```

I'm trying to do this with awk in a script to be able to do this on my multiple files through `for Fas in ${$(find *.fas)}; do awk script.awk<${Fas}`

I succeed to convert my sequences to one line fasta.

I would really appreciate help

Comment: Use the `{}` in editor for the data.

Comment: also, fyi there is a dedicated site for bioinformatics: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the filename always just three characters?

Comment: Actually, now you're asking it will be better to have the name of the original file before the three letters. I edit my question. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.fas' -exec \
awk -F'[>_.]' '
NF>1 {
    close(out)
    out = $NF
    sub(/[0-9].*/,"",out)
    out = $2 "_" out ".out"
}
{ print >> out }
' {} \;
```

I suffixed your output files ".out" so you could separate them from the ".fas" input files. Change that to suit your needs. You can use `+` instead of `\;` at the end of the `find` to run awk on multiple files at a time to speed things up a little if you have GNU find, but as written the above will work with any POSIX tools.

The above uses the FS (set by -F) to split each line that starts with `>` into it's relevant parts then recombines then to form the output file name for that line and everything that follows until the next `>` line. Then it just prints every line to the current output file name.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly ! (And thank you for your remark about output files suffix, it help me in another script) However, I don't really get what is happening, would you mind explaining a bit ?

Answer (score 1):

here is another take, just using "species" as the file name, so should aggregate all the variations in the same file.

```
$ awk '/>/{close(fn); n=split($0,a,"_|[0-9]+"); fn=a[n-1]} {print >> fn}' file


==> alb <==
>CL0073reads.fas_alb178305r
GCTGACGGCAACGTTAG

==> ang <==
>CL0073reads.fas_ang4836665r
TAGGCAGGCGTGGGGGTTTGT
>CL0073reads.fas_ang4864845r
CCTCTTCGGCCCTCA

==> atl <==
>CL0073reads.fas_atl679495r
CAAGGACCGTTAGGGGC
```

you can minimize the file open/close operations if the file is sorted by name and check for the previous name, but this is much simpler...